# c# JSON Property is a bool or a List of Jobjects and DeSerialization

Tags: c#, json

I have seen examples, but I am having problems using it for my situation. I think my problem may be the Sand boxed environment I need to work in.  I have a JSON property that can either be a single bool, or a List of Jobjects,( there may more types, I haven't run into yet though). Here is an example of the strings (there is obviously more to it, but this is the portion throwing me off)

```
     {
       "response" : true
     }
```

Or

```
     {
       "response" : [
          {
             "Name" : "string1",
             "Value" : 5,
             "String" : "5"
          },
          {
             "Name" : "string2",
             "Value" : 10,
             "String" : "10"
          }
        ]
       }
```

I will just handle immediately if it is a Bool, the array would be passed for further "processing".

I would like to use the most efficient method possible, which I believe is JSONConverter.  Could someone point me in the right direction?  Any help/criticism is welcomed.

Comment: Deserialize it into a property of type `JObject`, then inspect its properties and decide if you want to deserialize as a boolean or as an object. Oh, and complain to the maker of that API. That's just being difficult.

Comment: Agreed. I will try that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `JToken`, and check its `Type` property afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize your data into Dictionary. And then try to deserialize in dictionary again, and again... etc.. in this case you can control type of value in each of level in response. Good lack)

PS. Key of dictionary must be string, and value must be object. This way more easily.